# Mock method with namespace using GMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, namespaces, googletest, googlemock

I am writing unit tests using GMock/Gtest in C++. I'm failing to mock a method in a namespace. For example: `namespace::method_name()` in the called function.

Example code:

```
TestClass.cc.  // Unit test class
TEST(testFixture, testMethod) {
   MockClass mock;
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, func1(_));
   mock.helloWorld();
}
```

```
MockClass.cc  // Mock class
class MockClass{
MOCK_METHOD1(func1, bool(string));
}
```

```
HelloWorld.cc // Main class
void helloWorld() {
    string str;
    if (corona::func1(str)) { -> function to be mocked
      // Actions
    } 
}
```

In the above `helloWorld` method, `corona::func1(str)` is not able to call using above mock function.

Steps tried:

1. Added namespace declaration in EXPECT CLASS
   `EXPECT_CALL(mock, corona::func1(_));` -> failed to compile.
2. Added namespace declaration in Mock class
   `MOCK_METHOD1(corona::func1, bool(string));` -> failed to compile
3. Did different workaround solutions using namespace in mock class and test class.

I'm stuck at this point, unable to unit test the `helloWorld` method. The actual source code is more complex. How could I do this?

Comment: You cannot mock free functions...

Comment: @Jarod42, what's the way to bypass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock free functions, you have to create interface:

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual bool func1(const std::string&) = 0;
};

struct Implementation : Interface
{
    bool func1(const std::string& s) override { corona::func1(s); }
};

void helloWorld(Interface& interface) {
    string str;
    if (interface.func1(str)) { // -> function to be mocked
      // Actions
    } 
}
// Possibly, helper for production
void helloWorld()
{
    Implementation impl;
    helloWorld(impl);
}
```

and test:

```
class MockClass : public Interface {
    MOCK_METHOD1(func1, bool(string));
};

TEST(testFixture, testMethod) {
   MockClass mock;
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, func1(_));

   helloWorld(mock);
}
```