# Using the template only if the method exits

Tags: c++, templates, methods, containers, template-specialization

Can someone help me complete this code if a indexed container(map,set) calls `tool::exists_in` and has the find metod it will call the first method. if not, call the second method.

```
namespace tools {
    template<class TSource, class Ty>
    auto exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
        ->decltype(source->find())
    {
        return source.find() != source.end();
    }

    template<class TSource, class Ty>
    auto exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
    {
        return std::find(source.begin(), source.end(), item)
            != source.end();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> vector= { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> set = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout<<tools::exists_in(vector, 1);///should execute the first **tools::exists_in** method
    std::cout<<tools::exists_in(set, 1);///should execute the second **tools::exists_in** method
}
```

Comment: What version of the C++ standard are you using?

Comment: C++14 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, first function should be

```
template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
-> decltype(source.find() != source.end())
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return source.find() != source.end();
}
```

to have correct return type.

Then you might use some *"priority"* (for *best match*) between overloads as `int` versus `...`.
I prefer explicit ones with inheritance (and can even be done with unlimited level of priority):

```
struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority {};

template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(high_priority, const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
-> decltype(source->find(item) != source.end())
{
    return source.find(item) != source.end();
}

template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(low_priority, const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
{
    return std::find(source.begin(), source.end(), item) != source.end();
}


template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
{
    return exists_in(high_priority{}, source, item);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ec815c3efb1b4c7)

Comment: How I really do that priority thing?
Do i really need that priority? i just need to check if ```find``` method exists in that container.

Comment: and if exists, will call first method, if not, call the second method.

Comment: @danielgabor: Demo added. no issues here.

Comment: It does not work properly, I tested with the debugger, both (vector and set) call the second method, with std::find.
Just vector should call the second method, set should call the first one..

Comment: Oh, I copy paste your typo erroneous  `source->find` instead of `source.find`...

Comment: You mean in the first method? same thing, i tested, they go both to the second method, could you test aswell?

Comment: it works reversed, vector does not have ```find``` method, but your demo will execute the first method, and for the set, set does have the ```find``` method but will execute with std::find..

Comment: As I said, I take your sample... and you name the `vector` "set", and the `set` "vector", so the confusion.

Comment: Oh yeeeah, thankkkks,
one more thing, what that property (high,low) does?

Comment: You might look at [overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences). I just use naming about their purpose.

Comment: and why this uses inheritance? I cant relate how that helps

Comment: most derived has better match that base class (requires base to derived "conversion").

Comment: I want to add some gmock tests to check if a vector really access the linear method, and a gmock test if a set accesses the other method,
like you did here, but with template serialization:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942572/mock-method-with-namespace-using-gmock

Comment: I tried like you did in that link but it does not work..

Comment: I suggest to ask another question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705945/create-gmock-tests-for-template-specialization-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can use `has_find` with SFINAE to enable/disable overloads depending if TSource::find exists or not (see [Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9be69f71b6770dcd) example):

```
namespace tools {
    
    template <typename T>
    struct has_find
    {
        // use expression sfinae instead of obvious 
        // template <typename C> static char test(decltype(&C::find)); - which doesn't seem to work correctly in this case
        template <typename C> static char test( decltype(std::declval<C>().find(typename C::value_type{}))* );
        template <typename C> static int test(...);    
        enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
    };
    
    
    template<class TSource, class Ty>
    std::enable_if_t<has_find<TSource>::value, bool>
    exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
    {
        return source.find(item) != source.end();
    }
    
    template<class TSource, class Ty>
    std::enable_if_t<! has_find<TSource>::value, bool>
    exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
    {
        return std::find(source.begin(), source.end(), item) != source.end();
    }
    
}
```

**EDIT:**
Added static asserts to verify that `has_find` works correctly:

```
    using Set = std::set<int>;
    using Vector = std::vector<int>;
    using tools::has_find;

    static_assert(has_find<Set>::value == true, "Error: Set::find not found!");
    static_assert(has_find<Vector>::value == false, "Error: Vector::find found!");
```

Comment: I tested and it does not work..
For both set and vector goes to the same method, the second in your implementation.

Comment: Indeed. Have updated the SFINAE and added static assertions - it should work now. But I hope you get the point.

Comment: yes but i dont want to set the value true or false in the main, i want that the templates will detect automatically if the container has the find method.

Comment: the template DOES detect the presence of find method and set the value accordinaly. that's the point of SFINAE. read the code carefully.

Comment: what i mean is that, in the main, i dont want to set true or false values.. i want just to set: vector, set, map, etc.

Comment: where do you see true/false values set in main ? in what lines ?

Comment: @danielgabor: `true`/`false` in `static_assert` is just way to "test" code. you just need first snippet.