# Create gmock tests for template specialization methods

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, template-specialization, googlemock

I want to add GMOCK tests to verify if the container accesses the correct method.
For `vector` it should access the second method, and for `set` it should access the first method (because `set` has `set.find`).
This is my template specialization:

```
namespace tools{

struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority {};

template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(high_priority, const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
-> decltype(source->find(item) != source.end())
{
    return source.find(item) != source.end();
}

template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(low_priority, const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
{
    return std::find(source.begin(), source.end(), item) != source.end();
}


template<class TSource, class Ty>
auto exists_in(const TSource &source, const Ty &item)
{
    return exists_in(high_priority{}, source, item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use mock from free functions or template methods.

What you can do in that case is create a custom struct and check whether `operator<` (for `std::set::find`) or `operator==` (for `std::find`) is called.

Alternatively, you might create mock type for `std::set` and check that `find` method is called.

Comment: i added above a alternative way.

Comment: `std::set<MyType>::find` uses `MyType::operator<`, whereas `std::find` will use `MyType::operator==`

Comment: See that [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dbd480a32504abe) with custom type to instrument (you can mock instead) some operators (`<` and `==`) . You might see the used operator depending of find method used.

Comment: Use mock on `MyType`, instead of print, expect 0 calls of `==` when `std::set::find` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I did this alternatively way, for a vector, but it does not work, how i properly check if that method is called?

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual bool exists_in(std::vector<int>, int) = 0;
};

struct Implementation : Interface
{
    bool exists_in(std::vector<int> v, int i) override { tools::exists_in(v, i); }
};

class MockClass : public Interface {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, exists_in, (std::vector<int>, int));
};

**ADDED NEW**
TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(ExistsInTestMethod);

TYPED_TEST_P(ExistsInTestMethod, ExistsInMethod)
{
    TypeParam Container = InitVectorContainer<TypeParam>();

    MockClass mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, exists_in(Container, 5));
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 this is the alternatively way

Comment: I think more about `struct Mock {MOCK_METHOD(iterator, find, (int));MOCK_METHOD(iterator, end, ());};`.

Comment: iterator? wjy iterator? and why find and end?

Comment: I meant create a fake `std::set`, and check that `myset.find` is called.

Comment: i added above the way i EXPECT_CALL, how should i know what method it is called?

Comment: How should i check? in a expect call? using still the mock class